# Time machine won't recognize Lenovo laptop plugged in via USB to USB-C cable

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, usb, unix

I have a **Lenovo laptop**, running **Ubunutu 14.04 LTS**, and I want to connect its hard drive to my **MacBook Air** running **MacOS Catalina 10.15.6**. I have them connected via *newly bought* USB to USB-C cable, but Time Machine nor Finder will recognize that there is another device plugged in. My Mac will recognize if my iPhone is plugged in though. Also, when running `lsusb` on the Lenovo laptop, it does list out that a Mac is connected. But when running `diskutil list` on my Mac, no external disk is listed.

I'm trying to use the hard drive on the Lenovo laptop to store backups of my Mac. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t recommend network backup destinations for Time Machine - the tech is highly geared and better for direct attached storage that lets macOS format and manage everything.

That being said, you’ll want to connect gigabit Ethernet or Thunderbolt Ethernet and set up smb sharing. Then you’ll need to find a setup that works.

- https://www.vanwerkhoven.org/blog/2021/timemachine-to-linux-server/

You will learn a ton, so for that I’m excited when people set this up. For most people that need network backup, I would go with direct attached storage or networked over iSCSI or to an appliance like synology that will support you.

- https://kb.synology.com/en-global/DSM/tutorial/How_to_back_up_files_from_Mac_to_Synology_NAS_with_Time_Machine